# Detect use of display math: \everydisplaymath{}

Tags: counters, displaystyle

I would like to be able to detect if a display math environment was used: So, looking for a `\everydisplaymath{}` hook. Am not bothered if something like `$\displaystyle \frac{}{}` is counted or not.

In the MWE below I count the number of display math environments using `\everymath{}`, so looking to replace that line.

[image]

### Other Curiosities:

- It looks like the use `\[ \]` was not detected by `\everymath{}`?
- Using `align*` seems to have incremented the count by 4?

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{DisplayMathUsedCounter}
\everymath{\stepcounter{DisplayMathUsedCounter}}%

\begin{document}
Display Math Used: \arabic{DisplayMathUsedCounter}

Inline math should not be counted $F = ma$

Display Math Used: \arabic{DisplayMathUsedCounter} (this should be reported as 0)

\[
    E = mc^2
\]

Display Math Used: \arabic{DisplayMathUsedCounter} (this should be reported as 1)
\begin{align*}
    F &= ma \\
    E &= mc^2
\end{align*}

Display Math Used: \arabic{DisplayMathUsedCounter} (this should be reported as 2)

Ideally this should not be counted, but am ok if it is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$

Display Math Used: \arabic{DisplayMathUsedCounter} (this should be reported as 2 or 3)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean `\everydisplay`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{DisplayMathUsedCounter}
\everydisplay{\stepcounter{DisplayMathUsedCounter}}

\begin{document}

Display Math Used: \arabic{DisplayMathUsedCounter}

Inline math should not be counted $F = ma$

Display Math Used: \arabic{DisplayMathUsedCounter} (this should be reported as 0)
\[
    E = mc^2
\]

Display Math Used: \arabic{DisplayMathUsedCounter} (this should be reported as 1)
\begin{align*}
    F &= ma \\
    E &= mc^2
\end{align*}

Display Math Used: \arabic{DisplayMathUsedCounter} (this should be reported as 2)

Ideally this should not be counted, but am ok if it is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$

Display Math Used: \arabic{DisplayMathUsedCounter} (this should be reported as 2 or 3)

\end{document}
```

[image]